# Parent child relationship in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-10, odoo-view

I am working in odoo 10. I want to create parent child relationship in res.users but i don't know how to do this in odoo.

Suppose we have two normal user (`Boogeyman` and `Joker`) which belongs to a specific group. I want to create multiple users under him.The main purpose of doing this is that all users which are under `Boogeyman` They will not be able to see another date from `Joker` or any of his user. Same goes for `Joker` and associates.

Comment: IMHO, rather than creating parent-child relationship, your can separate the group. Let's say Boogeyman (and associates) is group A and Joker (and associates) is group B.

Comment: If i do so. I will have to create new group every time new Parent is here